# Openxml inserts italics at bookmarks.(several characters in a string are italics)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openxml-sdk

Here is the code for my work.

```
public void InsertValue(WordprocessingDocument doc, string bookMark, string txt)
    {
        try
        {
            RemoveBookMarkContent(doc, bookMark);
            var bmStart = FindBookMarkStart(doc, bookMark);
            if (bmStart == null)
                return;
            var run = new Run();
            run.Append(GetRunProperties());
            run.Append(new Text(txt));
            bmStart.Parent.InsertAfter(run, bmStart);
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            //not Exception
        }
    }
private void RemoveBookMarkContent(WordprocessingDocument doc, string bmName)
    {
        BookmarkStart bmStart = FindBookMarkStart(doc, bmName);
        if (bmStart == null)
            return;
        BookmarkEnd bmEnd = FindBookMarkEnd(doc, bmStart.Id);
        while (true)
        {
            var run = bmStart.NextSibling();
            if (run == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (run is BookmarkEnd && (BookmarkEnd)run == bmEnd)
            {
                break;
            }

            run.Remove();
        }
    }
```

There are still several auxiliary classes not written.Work process, first find the bookmark location, delete the content of the bookmark location, and then add it.I've also tried to add one Paragraph to the bookmark location.But that doesn't work.
Document to insert in bookmark eg:露点：*U*=0.15℃（*k*=2）；相对湿度：*U*=1.0%RH(*k*=2).Both u and K must be italics.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a new component.[Spire.Office.][1]
At the beginning, I didn't think of a solution, but I used the global search and replacement to determine whether the search location has bookmarks, which perfectly solved the problem.
Here is the code for my work.

```
var selection = document.FindAllString("U", false, true);
        foreach (var sec in selection)
        {
            var t = sec.GetAsOneRange();
            if (sec.GetAsOneRange()?.Owner?.LastChild?.DocumentObjectType == DocumentObjectType.BookmarkEnd)
            {
                sec.GetAsOneRange().CharacterFormat.Italic = true;
            }
        }
```

I didn't try to do this with openxml, but I think the principle should be consistent.
[1]: https://www.e-iceblue.cn/Buy/Spire-PDF-NET.html